# SYSDATE in oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I have a table as this and Im trying to select the highlighted entry as

`SELECT MESSAGE FROM MESSAGE_TABLE WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE`

But the above query returns nothing but ideally it should pick up the highlighted entry from the table
It's 6:15 PM currently in my location

Comment: What is the data type of `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff TIMESTAMP

Comment: And what does sysdate or systimestamp return if queried from dual?